# Can't open Jupyter Notebook from Mac OS terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, kernel, jupyter

I've been having some issues trying to open a Jupyter Notebook from the terminal on my Mac - it just gives me `killed: 9`. Could there something interfering with Jupyter? If so, how can I find out/fix it?

I tried restarting my computer and reopening the terminal - this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Some more info would be helpful. What command do you run to start Jupyter? What output in the terminal do you get?

An alternative to running/installing Jupyter from the terminal would be to use a desktop "click and run" Jupyter app.

For mac, [Callisto](https://callistoapp.com) would be a great option. It's currently in beta so you can try it out for free.